# apache solr Index pdf files with xml documents

Tags: solr

how to index pdf files in apache solr (version 8) with xml Documents
example:

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="id">filePath</field>
<field name="title">the title</field>
<field name="description">description of the pdf file</field>
<field name="Creator">jhone doe</field>
<field name="Language">English</field>
<field name="Publisher">Publisher_name</field>
<field name="tags">some_tag</field>
<field name="is_published">true</field>
<field name="year">2002</field>
<field name="file">path_to_the_file/file_name.pdf</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

UPDATE

how to set `literal.id` to filePath

Comment: the xml documents with the path to the pdf files are generated from other programmes

Comment: The most common way is to submit those PDF files to the [extracting request handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html). You can then use `literal.id` etc. to include custom data. Another option is to [use the TikaEntityTransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-tikaentityprocessor) with the Data Import Handler - parse the XML using the XML support then use the TikaEntityProcessor to process the PDF content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what i did

i am using solr DHI 
in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport_fromXML" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">

        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">data.import.xml</str>
            <str name="update.chain">dedupe</str>
        </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```

and the data.import.xml file

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="data"/>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" name="main"/>
    <document>
        <!-- url : the url for the xml file that holde the metadata -->
        <entity name="rec" processor="XPathEntityProcessor" url="${solr.install.dir:}solr/solr_core_name/filestore/docs_metaData/metaData.xml" forEach="/docs/doc" dataSource="main" transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer">
            <field column="resourcename" xpath="//resourcename" name="resourceName" />
            <field column="title" xpath="//title" name="title" />
            <field column="subject" xpath="//subject" name="subject"/>
            <field column="description" xpath="//description" name="description"/>
            <field column="comments" xpath="//comments" name="comments"/>
            <field column="author" xpath="//author" name="author"/>
            <field column="keywords" xpath="//keywords" name="keywords"/>
            <!-- baseDir: path to the folder that containt the files (pdf | doc | docx | ...) -->
            <entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" baseDir="${solr.install.dir:}solr/solr_core_name/filestore/docs_folder" fileName="${rec.resourcename}" onError="skip" recursive="false">
                <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="filePath" />
                <field column="resourceName" name="resourceName" />
                <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
                <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />
                <!-- for etch file extracte metadata if not in the xml metadata file -->
                <entity name="file" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" dataSource="data" format="text" url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}" onError="skip" recursive="false">
                    <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="subject" name="subject" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="description" name="description" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="comments" name="comments" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="Keywords" name="keywords" meta="true"/>
                </entity>
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

after that all what you have to do is create xml file (metaData.xml)

```
<docs>
    <doc>
        <resourcename>fileName.pdf</resourcename>
        <title></title>
        <subject></subject>
        <description></description>
        <comments></comments>
        <author></author>
        <keywords></keywords>
    </doc>
</docs>
```

and put all your file in one folder

```
"${solr.install.dir:}solr/solr_core_name/filestore/docs_folder"
```

the ${solr.install.dir:} is solr home folder

for the update in the question

how to set literal.id to filePath

in data.import.xml map the fileAbsolutePath to the id

```
<field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
```

**one last thing**

in this example the id is auto generated i am using

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="dedupe">
```

witch create a unique id based on the hash of the content for avoid duplication